# Why does typescript let this code to be compiled?

Tags: typescript, derived-class

if you run this code, you'll get an error: `obj.secretMethod is not a function`.

```js
interface BaseObject {
  hello(): void;
}

interface ObjectHandler {
  handleObject(obj: BaseObject): void;
}

class RealObject implements BaseObject {
  hello(): void {
    console.log("Hi");
  }
  secretMethod() {
    return "OK!";
  }
}

class FakeObject implements BaseObject {
  hello() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}

class RealHandler implements ObjectHandler {
  handleObject(obj: RealObject): void {
    console.log(obj.secretMethod());
  }
}

const f: ObjectHandler = new RealHandler();
const obj: BaseObject = new FakeObject();
f.handleObject(obj);
```

My question is why does TypeScript compiler sucessfully compile this code and doesn't even give any warnings, even with `--strict`? In comparasion with C# compiler: a C# compiler wouldn't compile this, because `ObjectHandler.handleObject(BaseObject)` method must be implemented as `ObjectHandler.handleObject(BaseObject)` and not `ObjectHandler.handleObject(RealObject)`, so, programmer must explicitly cast `BaseObject` to `RealObject` if he want to call a `secretMethod`. So why do TypeScript developers have decided to not to emit an error in situations like this?

Comment: It's [method bivariance](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant)... the fix here with `--strict` is probably to change your interface to `interface ObjectHandler {  handleObject: (obj: BaseObject) => void; }` (using function prop syntax instead of method syntax), taking advantage of [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#strict-function-types)

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) also: "The impact of strictly checking methods would be a much bigger breaking change as a large number of generic types would become invariant ".  I might be able to make this into an answer if I get off mobile (but anyone who gets here first is welcome to it also!)